# Facebook developer roadmap: Deprecating 'comments' field & Removing 'count' from 'comments'

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have noticed the [new changes in FB Developer]: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

I'd like to know what you think I need to change in my code.
I have wordpress and I have a function that counts the total number of comments, and of course it still need to works also after July 10.

```
function full_comment_count() {
global $post;
$url = get_permalink($post->ID);

$filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($filecontent);
$count = $json->$url->comments;
$wpCount = get_comments_number();
$realCount = $count + $wpCount;
if ($realCount == 0 || !isset($realCount)) {
    $realCount = 0;
}
return $realCount;
}
```

Is it as simple as changing:

```
$count
```

to

```
$total_count
```

or something else needs to be changed as well in the code?
Thank you

Comment: changing the name of your own variable will still be exactly the same code ;) - you could just activate the july 2013 changes in your app and try. it´s quite easy to test.

Comment: and if I enable it, and for some reson it doesn't work? Will I be able to "deactive" it once again?
If the name of the variable doesn't change it... so where should I change it?

Comment: yes, you can deactivate it. but it would be wise to keep it activated, because after july it will be activated in any case. i guess you did not even try it, so why don´t you just activate it and debug the result? ($filecontent)

Comment: I didn't try it, because I didn't know that I can deactivate it. Now that I know it I am going to try. I'll let you know.

Comment: OK, I have activated, waited 20 minutes and all seems to be working fine. I don't know how to debug ($filecontent) as you suggested, but the comments are still being counted well.
Should I debug something

Comment: var_dump($filecontent); - that is how you debug in php (at least one solution)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with both disabled and enabled July 2013 Breaking Changes, but in both cases it gives me NULL :(
Is it a good sign or it's wrong? The comments are being counted well... but this "null" sounds strange to me.

Comment: you have to debug it AFTER it has been filled with data, of course ;)

Comment: what do you mean with it? I have tried to add <?php var_dump($filecontent); ?> straight after the code posted above. This gives me NULL in the top of the webpage.
I have also tried to put var_dump($filecontent); in the loop of the homepage here (http://tinyurl.com/3ctvxng), where there is the total count after the whole counting code ( $commentCount = full_comment_count(); ) - but it also gives NULL.

Comment: ooh, I have tried to put the var_dump straight after this line ($filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);) and I get this text ( string(150) "{"http:\/\/sitename.com\/postname\/":{"id":"http:\/\/sitename.com\/postname\/","shares":3,"comments":1}}" 3 komentarzy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Roadmap:

> We are removing the undocumented 'count' field on the 'comments'
>   connection in the Graph API. Please request
>   '{id}/comments?summary=true' explicitly if you would like the summary
>   field which contains the count (now called 'total_count')

...file_get_contents is VERY bad, CURL would be better, but more complicated. the best way to use the graph api in this case is the php sdk: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

anyway, i guess those changes are needed:

```
$filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
```

...this is still correct, with  a var_dump right after this line (or after the json decode) you see that there is an "id". with that id, you have to make a second call to the graph api:

```
$comments= file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '/comments?summary=true);
```

the rest is easy-peasy basic php stuff, just do a var_dump of $comments after using json_decode again.

Comment: Hi, not sure if I got it. But I did the following: http://pastebin.com/P5Bi6yLT
The var_dump is saying - bool(false)

Comment: ok, this is really basic stuff, of course you have to fill the $id variable first, with the id from the $filecontent object...but this is merely a helping forum for developers, and not a channel to get work for free, no offense. for many of us, we develop for a living, we´re happy to help out once in a while but we really don´t want to help beginners for free the whole time, programming everything step by step for them ;)

Comment: Hi, I understand and thank you for your help. Just please tell me if this is the end result that you meant: http://pastebin.com/eHvraHdV - What I see now is "string(75) "{"id":"http:\/\/mysite.com\/thepost\/\/comments"}" 3 comments"  

If yes - great. If not, then I'll contact some dev for help. You don't have to give me the ready code if you don't want. I'll appreciate it anyway.

Thanks

Comment: one of the basic things is to debug. the whole time, even if it means to have a var_dump after every single line. if you know exactly what´s in your variables after every line, the rest is peanuts ;)
well, it looks good that way, i don´t now the real url but if there are 3 comments, it´s all good. should also work with the roadmap changes then.